# What is the difference between null and transparent brush in the Background or Fill

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

For example we have a Border. What the difference beetween these XAMLs?

1) **Background="Transparent"**

```
<Page
x:Class="App1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Grid
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Border
        BorderBrush="White"
        BorderThickness="2"
        Width="400"
        Height="400"
        Background="Transparent"
        PointerPressed="Border_PointerPressed"
        PointerReleased="Border_PointerReleased" />
</Grid>
```

---

2) **Background="{x:Null}"**

```
<Page
x:Class="App1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Grid
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Border
        BorderBrush="White"
        BorderThickness="2"
        Width="400"
        Height="400"
        Background="{x:Null}"
        PointerPressed="Border_PointerPressed"
        PointerReleased="Border_PointerReleased" />
</Grid>
```

Both of these borders looks identical. But what the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is if we set **null** background the Border will not support hit-testing, that's why **routed events** like PonterPressed **will not be raised**.

Conversely though, if we set **Transparent** background events **will be raised**.

To illustrate this let's write code-behind.

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;

namespace App1 {
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page {
        public MainPage() {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        void Border_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e) {
            Border border = sender as Border;
            if (border != null)
                border.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }
        void Border_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e) {
            Border border = sender as Border;
            if (border != null)
                border.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        }
    }
}
```

1) Let's use the first XAML, compile our app and run it. Try to tap inside the square. The square becomes red because the events are rised and the handlers calls.

2) Now let's use the second XAML, compile the app, run it, tap inside the square. Nothing happens because the events are not rised. The handlers are not calls.

Comment: The difference is very important. If you do not use Transparent, then the element is likely not to interact with the user like you expect.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, I found this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh758286.aspx#hit_testing explaining this rather well - see especially the second bullet point:

> **Hit testing and input events**
>
> Determining whether and where in UI an element is visible to mouse,
>   touch, and stylus input is called hit testing. For touch actions and
>   also for interaction-specific or manipulation events that are
>   consequences of a touch action, an element must be hit-test visible in
>   order to be the event source and fire the event that is associated
>   with the action. Otherwise, the action passes through the element to
>   any underlying elements or parent elements in the visual tree that
>   could interact with that input. There are several factors that affect
>   hit testing, but you can determine whether a given element can fire
>   input events by checking its IsHitTestVisible property. This property
>   returns true only if the element meets these criteria:
>
> - The element's Visibility property value is Visible.
> - The element's Background or Fill property value is not null. A null Brush value results in transparency and hit test invisibility. **(To
>     make an element transparent but also hit testable, use a Transparent
>     brush instead of null.)**  Note  Background and Fill aren't defined by
>     UIElement, and are instead defined by different derived classes such
>     as Control and Shape. But the implications of brushes you use for
>     foreground and background properties are the same for hit testing and
>     input events, no matter which subclass implements the properties.
> - If the element is a control, its IsEnabled property value must be true.
> - The element must have actual dimensions in layout. An element where either ActualHeight and ActualWidth are 0 won't fire input events.