# Switching between TabItems

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm pretty new to WPF and XAML.

Using the code below, I can switch between 2 TabItems, and the selected tab will turn red.
I am able to switch between the tabs when clicking on the text of each TabItem, but am unable to switch when clicking on parts of the tab where there isn't any text - such as the top right of the box.

How can I switch between tabs when clicking on the "whitespace" parts of the tabs?

Thanks.

```
<Window x:Class="testApp.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testApp"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="testApp" Height="600" MinHeight="375" Width="900" MinWidth="600">

        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50px" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="419*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" Background="#4B6C8B" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                <Grid>
                    <TabControl Name="tabbie" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" TabStripPlacement="Left" SelectionChanged="tabChanged">
                        <TabControl.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                                            <Border Name="Panel">
                                                <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Header" Margin="10, 2" />
                                            </Border>
                                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                                                </Trigger>
                                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </TabControl.Resources>
                        <TabItem Header="T1" Name="Test1" Width="51" Height="50px" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-3,-3,0,3" IsSelected="True" />
                        <TabItem Header="T2" Name="Test2" Width="51" Height="50px" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-3,-3,0,3" />
                    </TabControl>
                </Grid>
            </Border>

        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between null and transparent brush in the Background or Fill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20676923/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-transparent-brush-in-the-background-or-f)

Comment: set Transparent Background to "Panel" Border. Border with `null` Background is not clickable

Comment: @ASh thank you! Seems simple now.

Comment: you are welcome. another piece of advice: *Border* with name "Panel" can be very confusing. *Panel* is another and important class of UI elements